# How can I return to menu in Draw Something

Tags: ios, draw-something

After I solve a friend's painting, sometimes I don't want to send him a new drawing.
I wish to return to the menu but I can't seem to find how to do that without forcing the app to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option to do so in the current version of the game, you must force-quit the application and restart it.

To force quit on iOS (I'm listing this for others):

1. Press the home button to exit the app
2. Double-press the home button to bring up the open apps bar.
3. Press and hold the Draw Something icon until a red icon appears in it's the corner.
4. Press the red icon to close the app.
5. Press the home button and open the app again.

Comment: This is also how I do it. Shame that you need to go through the splash screen and opening animation.

Comment: Agreed. But it's a fairly new app (Although *very* popular), I'm sure this will be addressed in a patch very soon.

Comment: This has been partially fixed in the Android version. You used to have to force-close the app, like @JohnoBoy said above, but now pressing Back will allow you to quit the app gracefully, then log back in. Still not a solution but rather a cleaner workaround, but they're getting there. :)

Comment: I still prefer having the multitasking option the app has right now over the disability to go back to the menu. On a side note, how many Israelis are here? ;)

Comment: JohnoBoy - Stackexchange.com is packed with Israelis :)  http://www.google.com/trends/?q=stackexchange&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all

Comment: That's amazing, I had no idea :)